# font awesome toggle menu not clickable in custom wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome, custom-theme

my hamburger menu is showing on my custom wordpress theme its responsive too but you can't click on it for drop down menu

my code in functions php -

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>

            let mainNav = document.getElementById('js-menu');
            let navBarToggle = document.getElementById('js-navbar-toggle');

           navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
           mainNav.classList.toggle('active');
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');


in header.php - 

  <!--TOGGLE-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/721c0cc9d7.js"></script>

<!-- HEADER -->

<header role ="banner">
<nav class="navbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
             <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the WordPress way !
This is not how JS is used in WordPress or a file is called/added !
You have to use [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to include scripts in your theme.
Always refer to the source for reliable information [Including CSS & JavaScript](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)
After you have tried the WordPress way, if you can't get it to work, update how you tried to do it with the WordPress way and I'll help you :)

**

**--- EDIT ---**
A promise is a promise !
I'll guide you all the way :)
**1-** **REMOVE** :
**a-** FROM `functions.php`

```
    function wpb_hook_javascript() {
        ?>
            <script>

                let mainNav = document.getElementById('js-menu');
                let navBarToggle = document.getElementById('js-navbar-toggle');

               navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
               mainNav.classList.toggle('active');
                });
            </script>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

**b-** FROM `header.php`

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/721c0cc9d7.js"></script>
```

**2-**
I can see that you have generated a customized `JS` kit of Font Awesome.
Since I don't know what's inside it and what you have included and not, I'll be giving you the way to work with all the `JS` fonts then you'll be able, after understanding the concept, to work with all the fonts or your kit...

**a-** [Download Font Awesome](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/fontawesome-free-5.9.0-web.zip)
You'll find a `js` folder, and under that folder a file called `all.js`
At the root of your theme, same level as `style.css`, **CREATE** a `js` folder if you don't already have one.
In this `js` folder, add the downloaded `all.js` file and CREATE inside this `js` folder a new file called `my-js-file.js`.

**b-** In your `functions.php` add the following :

```
/**
 * Enqueue Font Awesome & Custom Scripts.
 */
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'font-awesome', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/all.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/all.js' ) ), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js-file', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/my-js-file.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/my-js-file.js' ) ), true );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );


/**
 * Filter the HTML script tag of font-awesome script to add data-auto-replace-svg attribute.
 *
 * @param string $tag    The <script> tag for the enqueued script.
 * @param string $handle The script's registered handle.
 *
 * @return   Filtered HTML script tag.
 */
function add_data_attribute( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'font-awesome' === $handle ) {
        $tag = str_replace( ' src', ' data-auto-replace-svg="nest" src', $tag );
    }

    return $tag;

}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_data_attribute', 10, 2 );
```

**3-**
Open `my-js-file.js` and add the following :

```
(function ($) {

    let mainNav = $( '#js-menu' );
    let navBarToggle = $( '#js-navbar-toggle' );
    navBarToggle.click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mainNav.toggleClass('active');
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I can't see any `id="js-menu"` in your provided `HTML`.
If your targets are correct it should work as expected, or you should rectify your targets.

**FINAL IMPORTANT NOTE**
Remember to use a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) for all of your modifications or they will be removed on the next update of the theme that you are using (unless you are developing a theme).

SYA :)

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'navbar-toggle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-1.js', array(), true );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'navbar-toggle' );

Comment: @jml try the WordPress way :) Take a look at the EDIT. If you still have questions, don't hesitate :)